# Azure certificate assign to vm

Tags: azure, ssl, iis, https

I am trying to add a certificate stored in the Key Vault on a VM machine but I am not able to, does anyone know how to do it?

I would like you to help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

## ```html
# Install a secret stored in KeyVault into an Azure VM's credential store.
$resourceGroup = [resource group name]
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name [VM name]
$vaultId = "/subscriptions/[subscription guid]/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/[vault name]"
$certStore = "My"
$certUrl = [KeyVault secret URL w/ version id]
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $vaultId -CertificateStore $certStore -CertificateUrl $certUrl

# Update the VM so the changes take effect.
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VM $vm
```

```html
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name tokensaletest.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/key.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:8000;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8000 https://tokensaletest.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com;
    }
  }
```

For more information refer to this [article](http://blog.baowebdev.com/2016/07/installing-a-certificate-from-azure-keyvault-into-an-azure-vm/) 
Deploy [Certificates to VMs from customer-managed Key Vault](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2015/07/14/deploy-certificates-to-vms-from-customer-managed-key-vault/)

Additional information: [Configure App Service Certificate to Azure Virtual machine with Windows or Linux OS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/10/26/configure-app-service-certificate-to-azure-virtual-machine/)